# Git init dentro de una carpeta de un repositorio git por error

Tags: git, control-de-versiones

tengo un repositorio git con diferentes carpetas. Por error realicé un git init dentro de una y seguí trabajando como si no pasara nada, pero guardando las modificaciones en un subdirectorio del programa principal. Ahora tengo dos git diferentes, cada uno de ellos con una rama Master y Branch diferentes y me gustaría hacer un merge quedándome solo con el git inicial sin tener que renunciar a todos los commits del git más joven.
Un esquema sería:

- Programa:
  - .git
  - Directorio
    - .git
    - Códigos

Estaría muy agradecido si alguien supiese solucionarlo.
Saludos!

Comment: el `git init` que hiciste en la carpeta hija es del mismo repositorio que el del padre?

Comment: Es el mismo repositorio inicializado en un subdirectorio. Digamos que quiero conservar el git de  "Programa" puesto que contiene varias carpetas estilo bin, src, test ... y creé, sin darme cuenta, un git en la capeta src. Desde ese punto, la carpeta src guarda las modificaciones y los commit a parte del repositorio original llamado "Programa".

Comment: Exacto, no estaba muy puesto en git ...

Answer (score 0):

todo el sistema de git se basa en el directorio oculto .git, que contiene los archivos, incrementales, referencias de indices y demás...

Entiendo por tu comentario que te quieres quedar con el proyecto que hay en DIRECTORIO, por lo que creo que lo tienes fácil:

- mueve DIRECTORIO al nivel de PROGRAMA
- borra el directorio PROGRAMA
- renombra DIRECTORIO por PROGRAMA

no te hace falta andar con merges, puesto que lo que necesitas es tener tu proyecto en un nivel superior. Solo mueve directorios (con su contenido, claro)

Answer (score 0):

Dependiendo del punto en el que se encuentre, podrá optar por una solución u otra..., pero es una situación bastante enrevesada.

Si se posiciona en el directorio padre y hace un *add*, debería notificársele una advertencia de estar añadiendo un repositorio embebido al principal. En esta situación, para conservar todo el historial del repositorio anidado, una posible estrategia a seguir sería crear una rama en el padre e inserir dentro de la misma el repositorio hijo en forma de submódulo. Es un proceso que seguro que viene mejor explicado en la [documentación](https://git-scm.com/book/es/v1/Las-herramientas-de-Git-Subm%C3%B3dulos).

Después sería el momento de proceder con la fusión de esa rama creada y la principal.

No obstante, como comento, todo depende del estado exacto del repositorio.